# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WindowsForms is installed but dosen't work

Tags: c#, blazor, visual-studio-2022

I made a WinForms project and in the Form1.cs I tried to use `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WindowsForms` but I have a CS0234 error, beceause Visual Studio 2022 doesn't find my package.

Error : Type or namespace name "Components" does not exist in namespace "Microsoft.AspNetCore.

[image]
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKRgK.png)[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKUCQ.png)[package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzrIK.png)

I want to know why my package isn't find by the IDE.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Did you [add that package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WindowsForms) to your project?

Comment: Yes you can see on the third screenshot

Comment: Post a [mre]: create a new project, mention which template and all steps.

Comment: Your project is a Net8 (preview) project?

Comment: There's only one screenshot in the question, containing a non-English message that I assume says the assembly is missing. Post code, error messages and  `csproj` contents as *text in the question itself*. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled, tested or translated.

Comment: Package references are added as `PackageReference` elements in `csproj`. The GUI makes this easier but still adds PackageReference elements. What does the `csproj` file of the failing project contain? Did you add the package to the wrong project perhaps?

Comment: No he's on the good project at the correct place but idk why the ide say that it's an incorrect name.

Comment: I translated and copy the error

Comment: @cp-21trd : in the future, post code and errors as _text_, not images.

Comment: @HH ok sorry men

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.